# What is this part called?

Tags: screws, fastener

I'm not sure this is the right place to be asking this but I'll give it a try. I have this bit of hardware from a pair of helping hands that I'd like to find more of. I'd describe it as a rod fastener of some sort. Not having any luck with those search terms however. Perhaps someone here has the proper name. Thanks in advance.

[image: helping hands and rod fastener]

Comment: It's called [throw-it-out-and-buy-a-new-one](https://www.harborfreight.com/helping-hands-60501.html) ...

Comment: That is a non-standard part. You will not likely find an identical one.

Comment: you could make one out of this and a piece of a bolt .... https://www.homedepot.com/s/rod%2520coupling%2520nut?NCNI-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call it a *cross-bored stud with retaining thumbscrew*, but there's nothing official about that.

As has been stated, it's probably a proprietary part and you likely won't find a drop-in replacement. You could fabricate one from a standard stud if you have machine tools available.